# Joining lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

So i've been praticing Haskell, and i was doing just fine, until i got stuck in this exercise. Basically i want a function that receives a list like this :

```
xs = [("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","e")]
```

returns something like this :

```
xs = [("a",["b","c"]), ("b",["e"])].
```

I come up with this code:

```
list xs = [(a,[b])|(a,b) <- xs]
```

but the problem is that this doesn't do what i want. i guess it's close, but not right.

Here's what this returns:

```
xs = [("a",["b"]),("a",["c"]),("b",["e"])]
```

Comment: sorry, from know on i'll add an output for every new question! i've updated it just now!

Comment: Thanks!  I've deleted my comment.  This is kind of an interesting question. :)

Comment: Yes it is! Because i understand what i have to do, i think i'm close, but my code is missing something! from what i know about Haskell, where i wrote "(a,[b])", it should be something else there, besides the b, am i right ?

Comment: to point out your mistake, when you say `[b]` you are actually saying "return a list made of the single element b"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the tuples in the final list, the most efficient way (that doesn't reinvent the wheel) would be to make use of the `Map` type from `Data.Map` in the `containers` package:

```
import Data.Map as Map

clump :: Ord a => [(a,b)] -> [(a, [b])]
clump xs = Map.toList $ Map.fromListWith (flip (++)) [(a, [b]) | (a,b) <- xs]

main = do print $ clump [("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","e")]
```

If you *do* care about the result order, you'll probably have to do something ugly and O(n^2) like this:

```
import Data.List (nub)

clump' :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> [(a, [b])]
clump' xs = [(a, [b | (a', b) <- xs, a' == a]) | a <- nub $ map fst xs]

main = do print $ clump' [("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","e")]
```

Comment: unfortunately the order of the elements matter. So "a" should be the first, "b" the second, and so on.. and can i do this with only the Data.List package ? because i'm studying this part now

Comment: Thank you! But if i do  the import of Data.List without the (nub) it doesn't work! if the nub function is part of this package, why the need to specify ?

Comment: @dcarou: I... have no idea.  Admittedly, Haskell and GHC keep changing too quickly for me to keep with, but based on the Haskell 2010 report and the antique version of GHC on my antique computer, it should work with & without `(nub)`.  What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @dcarou: If my answer is *the* answer to your problem, accept it and (optionally) upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use right fold with [`Data.Map.insertWith`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html#v%3AinsertWith):

```
import Data.Map as M hiding (foldr)

main :: IO ()
main = print . M.toList
             $ foldr (\(k, v) m -> M.insertWith (++) k [v] m)
                     M.empty
                     [("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","e")]
```

Output:

```
./main
[("a",["b","c"]),("b",["e"])]
```

Comment: and if i wanted to use only Data.List ?

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is that *you want to group "similar" elements together.*

Whenever you want to group elements together, you have the `group` functions in `Data.List`. In this case, you want to specify yourself what counts as similar, so you will need to use the `groupBy` version. Most functions in `Data.List` have a `By`-version that lets you specify more in detail what you want.

### Step 1

In your case, you want to define "similarity" as "having the same first element". In Haskell, "having the same first element on a pair" means

```
(==) `on` fst
```

In other words, equality on the first element of a pair.

So to do the grouping, we supply that requirement to `groupBy`, like so:

```
groupBy ((==) `on` fst) xs
```

This will get us back, in your example, the two groups:

```
[[("a","b"),("a","c")]
,[("b","e")]]
```

### Step 2

Now what remains is turning those lists into pairs. The basic principle behind that is, if we let

```
ys = [("a","b"),("a","c")]
```

as an example, to take the first element of the first pair, and then just smash the second element of all pairs together into a list. Taking the first element of the first pair is easy!

```
fst (head ys) == "a"
```

Taking all the second elements is fairly easy as well!

```
map snd ys == ["b", "c"]
```

Both of these operations together give us what we want.

```
(fst (head ys), map snd ys) == ("a", ["b", "c"])
```

### Finished product

So if you want to, you can write your clumping function as

```
clump xs = (fst (head ys), map snd ys)
  where ys = groupBy ((==) `on` fst) xs
```